# Is there a way to install sips on a Linux machine?

Tags: macos, alpine-linux, sips

I'm currently use sips on my Mac but wanted to run it on a docker image with Alpine. I was wondering if they are any way to run it into Alpine, since it doesn't seem to be available on Alpine and I have scripts that use sips and I didn't want to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it might help anyone, replaced with `imagemagick` on the scripts. Very similar functionalities.